# C++ Function overloading template value

Tags: c++, function, templates

I've been having trouble getting a templated function to be declared with a default value.

I'm not looking for something like `void do_thing<int val = 2>() {`, but rather a function that overrides another templated function with syntax like `void do_thing<2>() {`.

I'm aware that this is possible with classes, like this, for example ([from a tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3743/A-gentle-introduction-to-Template-Metaprogramming)):

```
template< int i >
class FACTOR{
public:
   enum {RESULT = i * FACTOR<i-1>::RESULT};
};

class FACTOR< 1 >{
  public:
  enum {RESULT = 1};
};
```

Where referencing FACTOR<1> would not go to the above class declaration, but the bottom instead. 
 The issue for me is that I can't do the same with declaring functions. Either my syntax is wrong or this isn't possible.

---

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
template<int tokens>
void skip_token() {
    for(int i = 0; i++ < tokens;) gettoken();
}

void skip_token<2>() {gettoken(); gettoken();};
```

In declaration syntax, it's pretty much identical to the code above except it produces a compiler error telling me I formatted my templates wrong.

---

If it **is** possible then let me know (how, of course). Otherwise, gently let me know if this kind of behavior isn't.

**EDIT:** *Fixed!*

To fix it, a function prototype is needed to be the base for both templated functions.
Such as `template<int tokens>
    void skip_token();` in a header file or above declaration.

Also, `template<>` is necessary before `void skip_token<2>()`.

Those were only examples. It's fairly easy to replace this code with something that would fit your needs, for the people who read this question.

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html "Template Specialization"

Comment: Just a note, your pasted code is broken, as you seem to be interchanging `i` with `I` in your enumeration computation.

Comment: @WhozCraig Guess I can't always trust tutorials, then.

Comment: You're missing the reduced template parameter list. You need a `template<>` above your specialization.

Comment: @WhozCraig I added `template<>` before `void skip_tokens<2>`. Compiler says it expects an initializer before the '<' token. Am I missing something?

Comment: You must be, or the code you have here isn't the code you're trying to use.

Comment: Try this: `skip_tokens` != `skip_token`. Check your names

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry about the name inconsistancy, that was me just testing around. Anyway, I'll look into the code. Thanks for the help, I'd mark the question as solved if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is *this* the kind of thing you're looking for? (A separate example, I know, but still...)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void gettoken()
{
    std::cout << "gettoken" << '\n';
}

// general decl
template<size_t n> void skip_token();


// impl
template<size_t n>
void skip_token()
{
    gettoken();
    skip_token<n-1>();
}

// specialize
template <>
void skip_token<1>()
{
    gettoken();
}

int main()
{
    skip_token<4>();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
gettoken
gettoken
gettoken
gettoken
```

Comment: Ah, a proper prototype was just what I needed. That fixed it.